# How can I call multiple commands as arguments to a function?

Tags: zsh

I want to write a "forever" function that I can run multiple commands until I manually kill it with Ctrl-C.
Basically, from the zsh command line, I know I can do this, and this works fine:

```
$ while {} { ls ; sleep 1 }
```

which will repeated call `ls` and `sleep 1`, forever.

I can't figure out a syntax to turn something like that into a function.
Something like:

```
forever() { while {} { "${@}" } }
```

which I want to then then call with something like:

```
$ forever ( ls ; sleep 1 )
```

It probably seems silly when `while {} {<commands>}` and `forever {<commands>}` is hardly very different.
But what I really want as my end goal is a "forever-sleep" function, where I can say something like

```
$ forever-sleep 5 ls -l
$ forever-sleep 5 ( ls -l a ; ls -l b )
```

and it will sleep `$1` seconds after executing the command(s) I give it, forever (until I manually kill it with Ctrl-C).

(I've tried lots of combinations and nestings of `()`,`(())`,`{}`,`[]`,`[[]]`,`""`,`''`, and such, and I just can't figure out how to get both the function and the command line not to have syntax errors, parse errrors, etc.)

So,

- Is there something similar to this "forever" idea already?
- Is this possible in a function? (I would prefer a function I can put in my `.zshrc` rather than having a separate executable shell script.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were almost there:

```
forever-sleep() {
   if [[ ! $1 -gt 0 ]]; then
     print "Usage $0 [time in sec] command -parameter"
     return 2
   fi
   local time=$1
   shift 1
   while true; do
      eval "$@"
      print -- "### finished: $(date) ###############################################"
      sleep $time
   done
}
```

The syntax then is `forever-sleep [time in sec] command -parameters`, like

```
$ forever-sleep 2 date +%s
1373873888
1373873890
1373873892
1373873894
...
```

A few remarks:

- `$1 -gt 0` implements a rudimentary check, if the first parameter is numerically by evaluating `$1 > 0`. A negative waiting time seems not sensible.
- I used `while true; do ... done`, but your `while {} {...}` syntax works, too.
- `shift 1` is used to discard the first argument to the function (which is saved in `$time`, so that later the `"$@"` variable can be used for convenience.
- `eval "$@"` in contrast to a mere `"$@"` makes it possible to do some more advanced stuff like

  ```
  forever-sleep 2 'foo=$(date); echo $foo'
  ```

  Please notice the single quotes in the latter command!
- The print invocation gives a visual separator -- like it or not `;)`

Comment: Beautiful. Thank you. The `eval` is what I was missing. (I knew about `shift`, but thanks for the completeness.)